# Facebook API access token - when I know uid and password

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-authentication, facebook-access-token

I have simple situation: I know both (user) UID and password and I want to create API requests, such as `https://graph.facebook.com/220439?access_token=...`.

What I **don't** want is to redirect user to Facebook page and prompt him to give me permission - since I know the credentials. Is there any way to obtain access_token directly? Or at least make the first OAuth request just once, receive **permanent** request token and then only switch it for regular access token when making API calls?

And btw, I use PHP SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Facebook are quite explicit that you cannot send credentials to their API in order to perform logins etc.

Comment: They used to have an offline_access setting for authentication but they've depricated that now. I'll double check but afaik you need to authenticate each time the token expires etc.

Comment: "we are now allowing the option to use access_tokens with a long-lived expiration time that can be renewed each time the user revists your app " - http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/